# Installing a specific version of sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, homebrew

I have an issue where I have failing specs on my CI build, but they pass locally.  I am using the same version of ruby on both, and the same sqlite3 gem is being installed on both.

The only difference I can find is that the CI server seems to use sqlite3 version:

```
3.7.17
```

Where my mac has installed sqlite3 version: `3.25.1`

The failing spec fails with a SQL syntax error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:  SQLite3::SQLException: near "WITH": syntax error: ;WITH included_items
```

I want to test this locally - to see if it is due to the Sqlite version.  I want to somehow downgrade my local Mac version of sqlite3 to the same version as the CI server.

I tried using brew but it couldn't seem to find any formulae for any other versions.

```
$ brew install sqlite3@3.7.17
Error: No available formula with the name "sqlite3@3.7.17" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the commit log for Formula/sqlite3.rb:

```
commit a9ad65c5f2fdc03aa47e4333fcd0df558136b099
Author: Jack Nagel <jacknagel@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 20 20:25:17 2013 -0500

    sqlite 3.7.17
```

So the basic idea is to run:

```
$ COMMIT=a9ad65c5f2fdc03aa47e4333fcd0df558136b099
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/$COMMIT/Formula/sqlite3.rb
```

For further details, see this gist:
https://gist.github.com/demosten/bdbc4f07c2ddbea0b8f0ad50a98ae5ff

Comment: I'm getting a 404 not found on the url:     https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/a9ad65c5f2fdc03aa47e4333fcd0df558136b099/Formula/sqlite3.rb` exited with 22. Here's the output:

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

Comment: i changed the url from `sqlite3.rb` to just `sqlite` and I now get this error:    Error: sqlite: undefined method `sha1' for #<Class:0x00007fc3be9cbfb0>

Comment: What changed between the errors reported in the comments and the green acceptance checkmark?

Comment: nothing I think your approach is correct, however I think the issue is my homebrew which is causing the error when installing sqlite3.  I could not get it to work so have abandoned this approach for now.